# Build ICU for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, icu

I need ICU library for iPhone. I have tried to build it from souce, however, I am getting this erros:

```
   clang++   ...  /Users/petr/Development/icu-cross-compile-master/icu-60-2/source/tools/pkgdata/pkgdata.cpp
/Users/petr/Development/icu-cross-compile-master/icu-60-2/source/tools/pkgdata/pkgdata.cpp:544:18: error: call to unavailable function 'system': not available on iOS
    int result = system(cmd);
                 ^~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:195:6: note: candidate function has been explicitly made unavailable
int      system(const char *) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(system);

sh ${ICU_SOURCE}/configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --with-cross-build=${PREBUILD_DIR} ${PREFIX}
```

My `PREFIX` configuration is as:

```
--enable-extras=yes 
--enable-tools=yes 
--enable-icuio=yes 
--enable-strict=no 
--enable-static 
--enable-shared=no 
--enable-tests=yes 
--disable-renaming 
--enable-samples=no 
--enable-dyload=no
--with-data-packaging=static
```

Or is there any other way, how to generate `libicudata.a`? The similar build script works OK for Android, Mac and Win. Only iPhone is problem.

Comment: Do you really need to build tools? They are actually a bunch of command line tools. If you build ICU without tools it will build as well without need for patching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `system()` is deprecated for iOS 11.

I think quick fix for you will be in using Xcode 6, instead of Xcode 9, so you can compile for iOS 7 as a target, where system() wasn't deprecated.

Or, if you really need iOS full compatible solution, you need to re-write ICU source code to use posix spawn functionality instead of system(). Check this answer for more details: [How do you use posix_spawn to replace the deprecated 'system' to launch opendiff in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046728/how-do-you-use-posix-spawn-to-replace-the-deprecated-system-to-launch-opendiff)

Comment: Thanks... replacing with posix_spawn helped.

Comment: Hi @MartinPerry. Could you share some details on what you replaced?

Comment: @Hons See my github: https://github.com/MartinPerry/icu-build-scripts in build_icu_mac.sh from line 107

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I have integrated that fix into my build scripts and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to successfully build ICU on iOS as a library is to build without tools with the configure flag --build-tools=no. The following is the complete set of configure flags I'm using to build for various platforms, android and ICU included.

```
    --enable-static=yes
    --enable-shared=no
    --enable-extras=no
    --enable-strict=no
    --enable-icuio=no
    --enable-layout=no
    --enable-layoutex=no
    --enable-tests=no
    --enable-samples=no
    --enable-tools=no
    --enable-dyload=no
    --with-data-packaging=archive
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just made a makefile which will download the ICU source and create a universal framework for Mac, Catalyst, iOS Simulator and iOS. This can then just be drag-and-dropped into your project.

https://github.com/dbquarrel/icu4c-xcframework

Might help you (though many years late).

My use was to enable the icu tokenizer in sqlite for iOS.